# Conjectured upper bound on the maximum value of the absolute value of the Möbius function in the poset of multiplicative partitions under refinement

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, partitions, upper-bounds

**PRELIMINARIES:**

Consider the poset $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$ of the (unordered) [multiplicative partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of $n$ partially ordered under refinement (for all $\lambda, \lambda’ \in \mathcal{P}_n$, we write $\lambda \leq_r \lambda’$ if the parts of $\lambda’$ can be factored including the possibility of the empty/do nothing factorization to produce parts of $\lambda$).

Let us for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\mathrm{pf}_o(n)$ and $\mathrm{pf}_u(n)$ as follows:

- If $n=1$, then $\mathrm{pf}_o(n)=1$ and $\mathrm{pf}_u(n)=\left \{ 1 \right \}$
- If $n$ has prime factorization $\prod_{i \in \left \{1, …, m \right \} } p_i$ (here $p_i$-s can be repeated with necessary multiplicity and satisfy $p_1 \leq \dotsb \leq p_m$), then $\mathrm{pf}_{o}(n)=(p_1, \dotsc, p_m)$ and $\mathrm{pf}_{u}(n)$ is the multiset $\left \{ p_1, \dotsc, p_m \right \}$.

Finally, let us for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\mathrm{ps}(n)$ as follows:

- If $n=1$, then $\mathrm{ps}(n)=1$
- If $n$ has prime factorization $\prod_{i \in \left \{1, \dotsc, m \right \} } p_i^{e_i}$ (here $p_i$-s are distinct and $e_1 \leq \dotsb \leq e_m$), then $\mathrm{ps}(n)=(e_1, \dotsc, e_m)$.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is clear that $\mathrm{pf}_o(n)$ is a least element of $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$.

On the other hand, let us for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ denote with $0^{(n)}$ the tuple $(0,\dotsc,0)$ containing $n$ zeroes. Consider the set of all non-zero multipartite numbers $\mathcal{M}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{N}^{n} \setminus 0^{(n)}$. For a multipartite number $N \in \mathbb{N}^{n} \setminus 0^{(n)}$, an (unordered and additive) partition of $N$ is a tuple $(\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_m)$ such that $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, $\lambda_1+\dotsb+\lambda_m=n$, and $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_m$ is a non-decreasing sequence under the lexicographical order. For a multipartite number $N \in \mathcal{M}$, let us denote by $\Pi_N$ the set of (additive and unordered) partitions of the multipartite number $N$. For all multipartite numbers $N \in \mathcal{M}$, it is clear that $\Pi_N$ under refinement forms a poset (we will also denote the refines relation on $\Pi_N$ by $\leq_r$.)

The following two claims are well-known in the theory of multiplicative partitions:

**Claim 1.** *For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it holds that $ (\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r) \cong (\mathcal{\Pi}_{\mathrm{ps}(n)}, \leq_r)$.*

**Claim 2.** *For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the poset $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$ is isomorphic to the set of partitions of the multiset  $\mathrm{pf}_{u}(n)$ partially ordered under refinement.*

These two claims might be useful for the solution to my problem.

**PROBLEM:**

In my research, the following maxima came up:

$$a(n)=\mathrm{max}  \left \{\left | \mu_{(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)}(\lambda, n) \right |: \lambda \in \mathcal{P}_n \right \}$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu_{(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)}$ is the [Möbius function](https://webpages.charlotte.edu/ghetyei/courses/old/S07.3166/mobius.pdf) in the poset $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$.

Based on numerical values of $a(n)$, I propose the following conjecture:

**Conjecture** *There exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following inequality holds:*

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N_{\geq 2}}: a(n) \leq n^{\alpha}.$$

It would be intuitive that $a(n)=\left | \mu_{(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)}(\mathrm{pf}_o(n), n) \right |$ (absolute value of the sequence [A317146](https://oeis.org/A317146) in the OEIS) since $\mathrm{pf}_o(n)$ is the least element of the poset $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$. However, this is unfortunately false (say, when $n=16$).

My question is *How can we (dis)prove **Conjecture**?*

**FAILED APPROACH AND COMMENTS OF SAM HOPKINS:**

To try the following approach came to my mind right away. Directly from [Phillip Hall's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132825/phillip-halls-theorem-on-chains), the following inequality follows:

$$\left | \mu_{(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)}(\lambda, n)\right | \leq N(\lambda, n),$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lambda \in \mathcal{P}_n$, and $N(\lambda, n)$ is the number of chains in the poset $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r)$ with $\lambda$ as their least element and $n$ as their greatest element.

As an immediate consequence, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{n \geq 2}$, we have the inequality

$$a(n) \leq \max \left \{N(\lambda, n) : \lambda \in \mathcal{P}_{n} \right \}.$$

It is probably not hard to prove that $\max \left \{N(\lambda, n) : \lambda \in \mathcal{P}_{n} \right \}=N(\mathrm{pf}_o(n), n)$. Thus, it would be sufficient to prove the upper bound of **Conjecture** for $N(\mathrm{pf}_o(n), n)$.

However, Sam Hopkins notes that $N(\mathrm{pf}_o(n), n)$ is of the order $n!/4$ and thus $N(\mathrm{pf}_o(n), n)$ would eventually surpass the required bound of **Conjecture**.

Furthermore, Sam Hopkins notes that when $n=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $(\mathcal{P}_n, \leq_r) \cong (\Pi_{k}, \leq_r)$ (this follows from Claim 1) and $\Pi_{k}$ is, in particular, the set of (unordered additive) partitions of the (natural number) $k$. Sam Hopkins then continues by noting that the Möbius function in the poset $(\Pi_{k}, \leq_r)$ is not well behaved (see, e.g, [Ziegler - On the poset of partitions of an integer](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(86)90092-0)).

I must also thank Sam Hopkins for making me aware of **Claim 2** and of its possible importance to this problem.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You asked a very similar question a few days ago, which it looks like you then deleted. Since that question had a few helpful comments on it, it might’ve been better to just edit that question, rather than delete it and post a new one.

Comment: @SamHopkins Please, see the new version of my post.

Comment: Okay, I have posted an answer and deleted most of my other comments (which the answer subsumes).

Comment: You wrote $\Pi_N$ and $\mathcal\Pi_N$, seeming to refer to the same poset, so I edited all occurrences to the former for consistency while fixing a typo.  I hope that that was all right.

Comment: @LSpice That is OK, thank you!

Comment: 18th version of this two day old question.

Comment: 1000th time of you commenting this on other people’s posts, Gerry.

Answer (score 2):

This is far from an answer, I am just trying to summarize some of my previous comments, in order to be able to delete them. The upshot is: I guess that your Conjecture is **true**, possibly even with $\alpha=1$, although it is likely pretty hard to prove.

In what follows I'll discuss some evidence/experimentation that leads me to believe your conjecture is correct. In order to explore your conjecture, it is helpful to think about "extreme" cases in terms of what the structure of the poset $\mathcal{P}_n$ might be.

*The case of $n$ square-free*

The first extreme case is when $n$ is square-free, say $n= p_1 p_2 \ldots p_k$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes. In order to test the conjecture, we may as well take these to be the first $k$ primes; so $n$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $n=p_k \#$.

In this case $\mathcal{P}_n \simeq P_k$, the lattice of partitions of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ ordered by refinement. This is a very well-studied and well-behaved poset. As mentioned, it is a lattice -- in fact, a "supersolvable geometric lattice" -- and in particular its Möbius function is very well-behaved.

It is known that $\mu_{P_k}(\hat{0},\hat{1})=(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!$, where $\hat{0}$ and $\hat{1}$ denote the minimum and maximum. It can also be shown based on known properties of $\mu_{P_k}$ that this is the biggest (in absolute value) Möbius function value in the poset. (In other words, in this case your intuition that the biggest value occurs between the min and the max is correct.) See for example the extended discussion in Example 3.10.4 in Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics," Vol. 1, 2nd edition, which should explain all of this.

Since the primorial $p_k\#$ clearly grows faster than $(k-1)!$, the conjecture is true in this case.

*The case of $n$ a prime power*

The "opposite" extreme case is when $n=p^k$ is a prime power. Again, we may as well take $n=2^k$ if we are trying to test the conjecture.

In this case $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the poset of partitions of the integer $k$ ordered by refinement. (Warning: this partial order is *not* the same as the more common [dominance order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order) on integer partitions.) This poset is much worse behaved, compared to the set partition lattice. For example, it is no longer a lattice. It was studied by Ziegler in [On the poset of partitions of an integer](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(86)90092-0), who showed other ways it behaves poorly: for instance, although it is ranked, its Möbius function does not alternate in value across rank. (See also this prior MO question: [Counting refinements of partitions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226656/counting-refinements-of-partitions) .)

So, to test the conjecture in this case, I decided just to do some numerical computations in [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/). The following code:

```
def f(k):
     P = posets.IntegerPartitions(k).dual()
     mx = P.maximal_elements()[0]
     return max([abs(P.moebius_function(p,mx)) for p in P])
[f(k) for k in range(1,21)]
```

spits out

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 12, 21, 34, 56, 101, 185, 311, 501, 845, 1313, 1908]
```

telling us the biggest Möbius function values for this poset of integer partitions for $k=1,\ldots,20$. (By the way, for this poset $\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1})=0$, so the intuition that the biggest value occurs between min and max is way off here; although the reason this zero value happens is not anything deep, it is just because this poset has a unique atom.) This sequence is not in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). But its growth rate is visibly less than $2$. So I would guess it always stays less than $2^k$, i.e., I would guess your conjecture is also true in this case.

As you mentioned at the end of your post, a very crude way to bound the Möbius function is by the number of chains in the poset, but the number of chains in this poset grows at a rate that is too fast (on the order of $k!$) for that to help with your conjecture. So to establish the conjecture in this case of $n$ a prime power you definitely need to use more sophisticated ideas which take into account cancellations in the Möbius function.

*The general case*

The general $n$ case is a mixture of the cases of square-free and prime power, so if your conjecture looks good in those cases, it is a reasonable bet that it is true for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! If you don’t mind, I suggested an edit where I replaced $\Pi_k$ with $P_k$ as to not interfere with the notation of my post. Also, I must say that Example 3.10.4 deals with $\mu_{(P_n, \leq_r)}(\widehat{0}, \pi)$ and not with $\mu_{(P_n, \leq_r)}(\pi, \widehat{1})$ which is what I’m interested in.

Comment: @TianVlašić: the example explains how every interval in a set partition lattice is isomorphic to a product of smaller set partition lattices. So in fact every Möbius function value is understood this way.